# Product Archive appearing only two products per category

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, archive, elementor

I have a store that is appearing only two products per category, when I open to edit with the elementor pops up all the products, but on the site only appears two, has anyone gone through it?

[Editing with the elementor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkbDb.png)

[in the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrYU9.png)

I need all products to appear on the site instead of two.

Answer (score 0):

Find within the theme options the Woocommerce option, and from there change the limit of products to display by category.

WordPress and the Theme are always higher in the hierarchy in terms of the number of posts or products to display, so even though from Elementor you want to show them all if the Theme says that only 2 can be shown, then they will not.

Comment: [https://www.papinelle.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/erro.png] 

It is already configured for four products, but still only two products appear.

Comment: What I notice is that you are not using the default widget for products that Elementor PRO has, so the problem could come from there. You probably need to review the way you built it, and also review the products.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1A56KRB0kTWer4zcYY2QGKd0SpcLMQG7V/view?usp=share_link

If you need help, I work as a web developer.

Answer (score 0):

on the wordpress dashboard goto settings then reading
that will allow you to choose number of posts you need to show.

You can check the screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHeih.png)